# Есть ли какой-то аналог конструкции synchronized из java в c++?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Иными словами, нужно, чтобы поток блокировал доступ к объекту для других потоков, пока работает с ним.
Объектов много, поэтому вариант с использованием mutex'ов для каждого не подойдёт. В java это было бы довольно просто сделать с помощью конструкции synchronized() {}

Comment: А ява не создает по мутексу на объект? Создает имхо. Может опенмпи атомик подойдёт?  Задачу опишите подробнее, раскажем. А синхронизед тут делают макросом

Comment: Java просто пихает синхонизирующий примитив в каждый объект совершенно не интересуясь мнением программиста. А в С++ у вас есть возможно реализовать синхронизацию эффективно.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock

Comment: Нет, аналога в C++ нет.